# My Tomcat 8.5 doesn't work properly

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat

I started AWS EC2, and installed Java and Tomcat 8.5
then I tried to access Tomcat and access Manager App to deploy..
But it's not loading front page.. just displaying 404 Error.
Of course I turned on Tomcat.. and configured the tomcat-users.xml file.
Can anyone give any ideas?

[image]

Comment: How did you install and did you do any configuration? IIRC there was an xml file to edit to enable the web GUI manager

Comment: yeah, I installed the tomcat using commands "sudo yum install tomcat8". and add these lines
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="root" password="root" roles="manager-gui"/>
in tomcat-users.xml